# phpunit path in MAMP

Tags: php, phpunit, mamp

I'm having a hell of a time with correctly installing phpunit with the zend framework in MAMP.

I created the zf alias and every time i create a new project i get "Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created." in the terminal.

I know i have phpunit installed.Just typing in 'phpunit' in the terminal gives me the manual. I have it installed in "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit".

my include_path in my php.ini file is 
      include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/svn/zendframework/trunk/library"

if i type in 'which phpunit' into the terminal i get '/usr/local/bin/phpunit' which i think may be the problem.

Any ideas would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Sorry to ask but what exactly is the problem here? -  this?->"Just typing in 'phpunit' in the terminal gives me the manual"

Comment: i'd like to create a new zf project and have the testing actions created in it.

Comment: i'm trying to go through tutorials that show how to set up phpunit with the zend framework and i can't get any of them to work. I don't think phpunit is being referenced/included right somewhere. I just have no idea where.

Comment: can you check if "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/" is already in your include path?

Comment: i copy/pasted my include path above. I'm not sure how else to check..??

Comment: yes, when i create a project it says "Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created."

Comment: sorry i missed that point in your question, Can u try restarting your machine once(Although i suspect This is not a PATH problem) I would like to check that way too. 
one more question, Did you use PEAR to install php unit? or did you install by forking github  repo and then building an executable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12983/discussion-between-eswar-rajesh-pinapala-and-david)